# How do I generate .net CORE SDK from swagger definitions?

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger, code-generation, openapi

I have a REST API which generates a swagger through /swagger endpoint. I need to generate a .net **core** client SDK for consumers so they can easily use it to connect to the service from .net **core** code.
The REST service itself is not developed in .net **core**, but in Node.js.

Is there a tool that will read the swagger definitions and generate a .net core sdk bindings ?

Options already evaluated(with no success):
a. openapi-generator (only generates .Net Framework code, not compatible with .net core)
b. NSwag (could not generate any useful code out of it)

Use any standard swagger and try to generate sdk for .net core. 
e.g. https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json

I am expecting a client side sdk project that will build on .net core.

Answer (score 3):

Please try [OpenAPI Generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) 
 (which supports both OpenAPI spec v2, v3) to generate C# .NET Core API client in 3 steps:

1) Download the Java JAR (http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/openapitools/openapi-generator-cli/4.0.3/openapi-generator-cli-4.0.3.jar)

2) Rename the JAR as "openapi-generator-cli.jar"

3) Run the following command to generate a C# .NET Core API client for the Petstore API (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/test/resources/2_0/petstore.yaml):

Mac/Linux:

- java -jar openapi-generator-cli.jar generate -g csharp-netcore -i https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/test/resources/2_0/petstore.yaml -o /var/tmp/csharp-netcore/

Windows:

- java -jar openapi-generator-cli.jar generate -g csharp-netcore -i https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/test/resources/2_0/petstore.yaml -o C:\tmp\csharp-netcore

Comment: Note this doesn't support oneOf, anyOf, allOf.

Answer (score 2):

You could use AutoRest to generate .net code client.

https://github.com/Azure/autorest

Install with npm and lauch cmd

example :

## generate the client

> autorest --input-file=https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/ --output-folder=c:\petstore --namespace=Petstore --csharp